# NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]' was called on null in GET request in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to display a list from api with GET request. But it keeps showing this error:

```
NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]' was called on null.
 Receiver: null
 Tried calling: []("depId")
```

The thing is I don't use depId at all for this request and it's not even in the object that I'm using to make this request so I don't know from where it gets null value because when I use it in my previous request it works totally fine.

Here is the API request

```
 static Future<List<Athlete>> getAthletesByTeamKey(
      int depId, int teamId) async {
    try {
      final response = await http.get(
          Uri.parse(
              '$uri/get-athletes-by-team-key?depId=$depId&teamId=$teamId&page=0&length=50'),
          headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Basic ...',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept': 'application/json'
          });
      print('Response status: ${response.statusCode}');
      print('Response body: ${response.body}');

      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        if (response.body.isNotEmpty) {
          print('response.body.isNotEmpty');
          List jsonResponse = json.decode(utf8.decode(response.bodyBytes));
          return jsonResponse
              .map((athlete) => Athlete.fromJson(athlete))
              .toList();
        } else if (response.body.isEmpty) {
          print('response.body.isEmpty');
          throw Exception();
        }
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print('catch');
      logger.e(e.toString());
    }
    return getAthletesByTeamKey(depId, teamId, context);
  }
```

It prints the `print('response.body.isNotEmpty');`and then it goes into catch

My Athlete object

```
List<Athlete> athleteFromJson(String str) =>
        List<Athlete>.from(json.decode(str).map((x) => Athlete.fromJson(x)));
    String athleteToJson(List<Athlete> data) =>
        json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())));

class Athlete {
  late int id;
  late String firstName;
  late String lastName;
  late String fatherName;
  late int currentMonthPresences;
  late bool isSelected = false;
  late bool hasDebt;
  Department? department;
  Team? team;

  Athlete(
      {required this.id,
      required this.firstName,
      required this.lastName,
      required this.fatherName,
      required this.currentMonthPresences,
      this.isSelected = false,
      required this.hasDebt,
      this.department,
      this.team});

  Athlete.newSelectedAthlete(this.id, this.department, this.team); //I use it for another screen

  factory Athlete.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Athlete(
        id: json['id'],
        firstName: json['firstName'],
        lastName: json['lastName'],
        fatherName: json['fatherName'],
        currentMonthPresences: json['currentMonthPresences'],
        hasDebt: json['hasDebt'],
        department: Department.fromJson(json['department']),
        team: Team.fromJson(json['team']),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        'id': id,
        'firstName': firstName,
        'lastName': lastName,
        'fatherName': fatherName,
        'currentMonthPresences': currentMonthPresences,
        'isSelected': isSelected,
        'hasDebt': hasDebt,
        'department': department,
        'team': team,
      };
}
```

Department object

```
class Department {
  int id;
  String depName;

  Department({required this.id, required this.depName});

  factory Department.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Department(
        id: json['id'],
        depName: json['depName'],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "id": id,
        "depName": depName,
      };
}
```

Team object

```
class Team {
  final TeamKey teamKey;
  final String teamName;
  final int hidden;
  final User user;
  final String depName;

  Team(
      {required this.teamKey,
      required this.teamName,
      required this.hidden,
      required this.user,
      required this.depName});

  factory Team.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Team(
        teamKey: TeamKey.fromJson(json['teamKey']),
        teamName: json['teamName'],
        hidden: json['hidden'],
        user: User.fromJson(json['user']),
        depName: json['depName'],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        'teamKey': teamKey,
        'teamName': teamName,
        'hidden': hidden,
        'user': user,
        'depName': depName,
      };
}
```

and the TeamKey object that has the variable depId but I don't use it at all

```
class TeamKey {
  int depId;
  int teamId;

  TeamKey({required this.depId, required this.teamId});

  factory TeamKey.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => TeamKey(
        depId: json['depId'],
        teamId: json['teamId'],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "depId": depId,
        "teamId": teamId,
      };
}
```

The screen I'm trying to display my list

```
class AthleteScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const AthleteScreen(this._team, {Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  final Team _team;

  @override
  State<AthleteScreen> createState() => _AthleteScreenState();
}

class _AthleteScreenState extends State<AthleteScreen> {
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  final myController = TextEditingController();
  final controller = TextEditingController();

  Future<List<Athlete>>? futureAthletebyTeamKey;
  Future<List<Presence>>? futureGetPresences;
  final List<Athlete> _athlete = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    futureAthletebyTeamKey = ApiService.getAthletesByTeamKey();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(children: [
              const SizedBox(
                height: 10,
              ),
              FutureBuilder<List<Athlete>>(
                future: futureAthletebyTeamKey,
                builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.hasData) {
                    List<Athlete> _athlete = snapshot.data;
                    return ListView.builder(
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        cacheExtent: 34,
                        primary: true,
                        physics: const ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                          top: 10,
                          bottom: 56,
                        ),
                        itemCount: _athlete.length,
                        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int i) {
                            return CheckboxListTile(
                              title: Column(
                                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                children: [
                                  Row(
                                    children: [
                                      Text(
                                        'ID: ${_athlete[i].id}',
                                        style: const TextStyle(
                                            color: Colors.blue, fontSize: 14),
                                      ),
                                      const SizedBox(
                                        width: 5,
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                  Row(
                                    children: [
                                      Flexible(
                                        child: Text(
                                          '${_athlete[i].lastName} ${_athlete[i].firstName}',
                                          style: const TextStyle(
                                              color: Colors.black,
                                              fontFamily: 'Cera',
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                              fontSize: 18),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                  const SizedBox(
                                    height: 5,
                                  ),
                        });
                  } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                    logger.e('${snapshot.error}');
                  }
                  return const Center(
                    heightFactor: 20,
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator.adaptive(),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ]),
          ),
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            child: Container(
              width: double.infinity,
              height: 60,
              child: ElevatedButton(
                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                    disabledBackgroundColor: Colors.grey),
                onPressed: () async {
                        Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(
                            SelectedAthletes.routeName,
                            arguments: selectedAthlete.toList());
                      }),
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    const Text(
                      'ΝΕΧΤ',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontSize: 18),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I'll be very thankful if someone took time to help me! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You actually use depId.
So let's follow along with your JSON.

When you decode the athlete you do:

```
  factory Athlete.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Athlete(
        ...
        department: Department.fromJson(json['department']),
        team: Team.fromJson(json['team']),
      );
```

So the Athlete.fromJson() is calling Team.fromJson(). Let's look at it

```
 factory Team.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Team(
        teamKey: TeamKey.fromJson(json['teamKey']),
        ...
      );
```

Team.fromJson() iscalling TeamKey.fromJson(). Let's look at that.

```
 factory TeamKey.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => TeamKey(
       depId: json['depId'],
       teamId: json['teamId'],
     );
```

TeamKey.fromJson() wants the 'depId'.
Your JSON should look like:

```
team: {
  teamKey: {
    depId: ...
  }
}
```

Double check your JSON to make sure your structure is good. Your code will actually decode along with Athlete his Team and TeamKey where you access 'depId'.

You should either remove the teamKey, or resolve it by following along the path of the original JSON you are trying to parse and see if your structure is in align with it.

Comment: Oh I see thanks for making it clear to me! But why it says is null in this request but in the previous where I use it directly it displays just fine?

Comment: Can you please give me a snippet of some JSON that works and some that does not?

Comment: The JSON that works : [{"teamKey":{"depId":3,"teamId":278},"teamName":"KAXRIS","hidden":0,"user":{"id":30,"username":"kaxris","role":"ROLE_COACH"},"depName":"SWIMMING"}]

Comment: The JSON that doesn't work: [
    {
        "id": 14037,
        "firstName": "lydia",
        "lastName": "west",
        "fatherName": "John",
        "department": {
            "id": 3,
            "depName": "SWIMMING"
        },
        "team": {
            "teamId": 278,
            "teamName": "KAXRIS"
        },
        "hasDebt": false,
        "currentMonthPresences": 2
    }]

Comment: The JSON that doesn't work is a list of maps but I can't can't paste it all. Thanks for your time